# Copy a part of a geometry - TI-Nspire CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

Is it possible to copy a part of a geometry from a sheet to another sheet? I am using TI-Nspire CAS calculator.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you using the Ti-Nspire CX CAS or TI-Nspire CAS?

Comment: Hi @JohnP, I'm using TI-Nspire CAS.

Comment: Sorry, i don't have a regular CAS or know how it works